# When are you "fascinated with" something, and when are you "fascinated by" it?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Am I fascinated *with* consumer technology or fascinated *by* it? What about a book, an object, or a philosophical idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**With:** If the object of the fascination is something that can be held, handled, or manipulated (Rubik's cube for example), then someone can be fascinated "with" it.

> *I was fascinated with his car.*

**By:** If - for example - someone is reading an interesting article, they may be fascinated "by" it.

> *I was fascinated by her voice.*

Source: [Yahoo Answers](https://web.archive.org/web/20121219013542/http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081011062936AAF2h7k).

Comment: What about a philosophical idea? This is a "thing", but not something you can hold. Or "consumer technology"? This is a class of things, so which does it fit in?

Comment: I'll use by with both of them. They're ideas or concepts rather than being physical things.
I checked Oxford, Webster and Longman. All were using examples using "by".

Comment: What about Japan?  Can I be both fascinated *with* Japan and fascinated *by* Japan because it's a thing and a whole bunch of ideas?

Answer (score 1):

(i) "**by**" names the agent responsible for the action.

**By** is commonly the preposition whose object is the agent of the passive verb:

*I was fascinated **by** her voice*: This is the passive form of *Her voice fascinated me.*

(ii) "with" names the instrument that was used for/caused the action.

*I was fascinated with his car*. Here, **fascinated** is an adjective and *"with his car"* modifies fascinated.