# Is it "I developed a fascination with machines" or "for machines"?

Tags: differences

What is correct?
I developed a fascination with machines or for machines?

Comment: Both 'with' and 'for' are okay, but 'a fascination for' sounds more colloquial,

Comment: I've rarely encountered *fascination for* in reference to the object or cause of the fascination. Where have you seen it? Also see *[When are you “fascinated with” something, and when are you “fascinated by” it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27398)*

Comment: This ngram might be of interest: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+fascination+for%2C+a+fascination+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20fascination%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20fascination%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @YosefBaskin - Is ‘colloquial’ a good thing or a bad thing in this case?